# whys is my jquery ajax call returning and error when calling local webservice

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am attempting to make a request using Ajax but am receiving the error response
`{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}`. Here is the code for my Ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost:8080/persons/all",
        /* url : "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2", */
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        contentType : "application/json",
        ajaxSuccess : function(data) {
            alert("Success " + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        beforeSend : function(data) {
            alert("BeforeSend " + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        complete : function(data) {
            alert("Complete " + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        success : function(data) {
            alert("Success " + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error : function(data) {
            alert("Error " + JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the result of calling http://localhost:8080/persons/all on the browser

```
{
  "2": {
    "id":"2",
    "firstName":"Steve",
    "lastName":"Smith",
    "age":21
  },
  "1": {
    "id":"1",
    "firstName":"Steve",
    "lastName":"Smith",
    "age":21
  }
}
```

Ajax call to this link works though https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2
Here is the result

```
{
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseText":"{
    \"page\":2,
    \"per_page\":3,
    \"total\":12,
    \"total_pages\":4,
    \"data\":[
      {
        \"id\":4,
        \"first_name\":\"Eve\",
        \"last_name\":\"Holt\",
        \"avatar\":\"128.jpg\"
      },
      {
        \"id\":5,
        \"first_name\":\"Charles\",
        \"last_name\":\"Morris\",
        \"avatar\":\"128.jpg\"
      },
      {
        \"id\":6,
        \"first_name\":\"Tracey\",
        \"last_name\":\"Ramos\",
        \"avatar\":\"o/128.jpg\"
      }
    ]
  }",
  "responseJSON": {
    "page":2,
    "per_page":3,
    "total":12,
    "total_pages":4,
    "data":[
      {
        "id":4,
        "first_name":"Eve",
        "last_name":"Holt",
        "avatar":"128.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id":5,
        "first_name":"Charles",
        "last_name":"Morris",
        "avatar":"128.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id":6,
        "first_name":"Tracey",
        "last_name":"Ramos",
        "avatar":"128.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status":200,
  "statusText":"OK"
}
```

Why is the call to my local url not working? My webservice is in port 8080 and my web app is in 8081. I have been strugging with this for last 10 days. Please help !!!

Comment: I've added formatting for your code blocks and included a bit more of a lead-in to the question at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks Henry.......

Comment: What does the network tab of the developer tools say? What does the console say?

Comment: If the app and webservice are on different ports, the same-origin policy will prevent the call unless the webservice sends the appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: I can see the json data in network -> reponse portion of the browser. But the json call goes to error. Why is it so ? I am breaking my head for the last 10 days. Here is my code

Comment: public class C00Controller {

 private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(C00Controller.class);

 @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081")
 @RequestMapping(value = "/ListOfProjects9", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
 public @ResponseBody List<Project> ListOfProjects9() {

  List<Project> projects = ProjectControl.List_Of_Projects_From_TCIM(null);

  return projects;
 }

}   
I see the json object in the browers Network -> response  window. But my json call always goes to error. Please help !

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
  url : 'http://localhost:8080/ListOfProjects9?cors=true',
  type : 'GET',
  dataType : 'JSONP',
  jsonpCallback : 'callbackFnc',
  async : false,
  crossDomain : true,
  contentType : "application/json",  
  success : function(data) {
   alert("Success " + JSON.stringify(data));
  },
  error : function(xhr, status, error) {
   alert("Error " + JSON.stringify(data));
  },

 });
});

Comment: Please Help !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

error occurred for (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)) mechanism 
you can't send request from a domain to other domain !!! or  request  from local to other domain !!!

you can send request to other domain that http header CORS is access to  other doamin !

Comment: I am seeing these warning messages

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/persons/all. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/persons/all. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Comment: I am new to ajax. Appreciate if your advice would be detailed instructions

Comment: you should add http header to "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"

1.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://sample.com 
1.or  [Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ]  to access all domain control
2.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT

3.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

Comment: add  [ Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ]  =>  for access all domain